# Finding limit of a function with more than one variable using mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization, mathematica-online

[image]

I want to find the limit as t approaches infinity of the function u(x,t) using mathematica. Can someone please help me do this?

Comment: there is no limit. Because $\cos(t)$ has no limit as $t$ goes to infinity. You do not need Mathematica for this :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue it raises is not really a Mathematica issue but a matter of the OP not having grasped the relevant mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, this function has no limit. Indeed, the more transparent version:

```
Limit[Cos[t], t -> Infinity]
```

returns Indeterminate, as you might expect. While the limit does not exist, you can get bounds on the limit. For example,

```
MaxLimit[Cos[t], t -> Infinity]
```

and

```
MinLimit[Cos[t], t -> Infinity]
```

return 1 and -1. For a function of two variables, it's the same thing. For example,

```
MaxLimit[Cos[t] + Exp[-t] x, t -> Infinity]
```